# HTML5 button disappears when going to fullscreen canvas

Tags: html, button, canvas

I'm writing a javascript game and I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get my game work with the requestFullscreen feature. My game exists of a menu with a button (html5 button) to start the gameloop. But when I go in fullscreen, the menu goes to fullscreen, but the button that can start the gameloop, disappears. I was wondering if it's possible to still have html5 buttons on screen while being in canvas fullscreen mode.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, nevermind. The fullscreen function isn't that handy, I don't think I will be using it (it disables a few gamecontrols while being fullscreen, security reasons) and it only centers my canvas and makes the rest black, it isn't really fullscreen. (chrome). And on firefox it stretches the width and height to fit the screen, which makes it quite ugly. So thank you, but I think I won't use it.

Comment: Put all the HTML for your game inside a containing <div> and make that fullscreen. You can control the height/width, stretch/no-stretch with CSS - [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode). Don't give up on fullscreen yet, it's great.

Comment: Okay, thank you will try that tomorrow :D

Comment: It worked the div methode, thanks :D

Answer (score 6):

Requesting full screen mode will make the element (and its children) full-screen. Anything else will be hidden.

As the canvas element can't have children you need to wrap it and the elements you want to see in a parent container, ie. a `div` element.

```
<div id="cover">
    <canvas ... ></canvas>
    <button ... >My button</button>
</div>
```

Now you can request full-screen mode on `cover`.

Note however: the full-screen API isn't final and do behave different from browser to browser. You may need to add specific CSS for each element for full-screen mode versus non-full-screen mode.